# Machine Code (.asm & movsx)

Tags: assembly

I'm looking at these problems in my book and I am trying to figure out what they mean exactly.

```
.data 
one WORD 8002h 
two WORD 4321h 
.code 
mov   edx,21348041h 
movsx edx,one 
movsx edx,two
```

^ EDX starts out with a value of 21348041 hex right? Then because of movsx edx adds FFFFF8002 hex? Then edx adds FFFFF4321 hex? Confusing, but I am assuming the book is explaining that movsx converts to signed?

Comment: You say "machine code"? Which machine? There's more than one kind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is correct, but not "adds". `mov*` moves data.

Because you request the data to be treated as signed, and you're using less than one word of data (assuming a 32 bit architecture), the actual data moved will be padded to the left with `1` if the source number has the left-most bit set (ie negative).

Note the addendum at the end. Because `0x4321` isn't negative (less than `0x8000`), even if you treat it as signed it's still positive. It will move the literal value you give it.